# express.js routing behavior

Tags: node.js, express

I am beginning with express.js and I am wondering why the following code:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();


app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('First middleware');
    next();
});

app.use('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Second middleware');
    res.send('<h1>The add-product page!</h1>');
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Third middleware');
    res.send('<h1>Hello from Express!</h1>');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

..when called with `localhost:3000/add-product` from chrome/firefox etc, produces

```
First middleware
Second middleware
First middleware
Third middleware
```

in the console?

Comment: you sure you want `app.use` and not `app.get` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the browser is making two requests to your server:

```
/add-product
/favicon.ico
```

Then, to understand the routing, you have to understand the difference in route matching between `app.use()` and `app.get()`.

`app.get()` matches only if the route definition **matches the whole requested URL**.  The same is true for `app.post()`, `app.put()`, `app.delete()` and `app.all()`.

`app.use()` matches if the route definition is at least **partial match to the requested URL**.

Note also that `app.get()` matches only GET requests while `app.use()` matches any HTTP verb (including POST, PUT, DELETE) though this difference doesn't matter in this particular example since both the requests happening here are GET requests.

In fact, the difference between `app.use()` and `app.all()` (who both match any HTTP verb) is that `app.all()` needs a full match and `app.use()` accepts only a partial match.

Also, the routes are checked for matches in the order specified in your code.

**The /add-product routing**

So, when the browser requests `/add-product`, you get this:

`app.use('/', ...)` matches because `/`  is a partial match to `/add-product`.

`app.use('/add-product', ...)` matches because `/add-product` is a match to `/add-product`

The `/add-product` route then sends a response and does not call `next()` so routing is done for that request and the third route is not checked at all.

**The /favicon.ico routing**

Then, when the browser requests `/favicon.ico`, you get this:

`app.use('/', ...)` matches because `/`  is a partial match to `/favicon.ico`.

`app.use('/add-product', ...)` does not match because it is not at least a partial match for `/favicon.ico`

Then, it checks your third route this time and it is a partial match for `app.use('/', ...)` which sends a response and doesn't call `next()` so routing is done for that request.

---

Note: It's important to pick `app.get()` or `app.use()` appropriately.

Comment: thank you, the  /favicon.ico routing part was what I was missing. However, now(a couple of hours later), when I run THE SAME program it looks like the /favicon.ico routing thing doesn't happen. Weird..

Comment: @Dr_V - I don't know why that would happen unless the browser is "remembering" that `/favicon.ico` doesn't give it an icon and thus not requesting it.  I can't reproduce that behavior with your code when using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Two logs at the end - `First` and `Third` is for `favicon.ico` request. When you return a html string at `/add-product`, browse will auto makes a request like `GET favicon.ico`.

If you want to prevent it, at second middleware, return a html string like:

```
res.send('<head><link rel="icon" href="data:,"></head><h1>The add-product page!</h1>');
```

Comment: @Dr_V the route path is `/` this mean it match any request, include request GET `/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 1):

your browser is making two network calls: one to `/add-product`, and one to `/favicon.ico`. verify this by examining the network activity tab of your browser's dev tools, and/or make the same request from the command line (with wget or similar) and see what happens.

the first request passes through your first and second middleware functions, and the second request passes through your first and third middleware functions.